# Proving a certain lemma about subgroups of $A_n$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

In proving $A_n$ is simple for $n\neq4$, my teacher established the cases 1, 2, 3 as obvious, then proved the case 5, and proceded by induction on the rest. In the midst of that induction, he stated that if $N$ is a (normal) subgroup of $A_n$ such that it acts transitively on the set $\{1,\dotsc,n\}$, then $NA_{n-1}=A_n$. How do I prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Frattini Argument**;

Let $G$ be a group acting on a set $\Omega$ and $N$ be a subgroup of $G$. If action of $N$ is transitive then $$G=NStab(x)$$

You question can be directly answered by Frattini argument as $A_{n-1}=Stab(n)$.

**Proof:** Let $g\in G$ and $x\in \Omega$. Clearly, $gx\in \Omega$. Since the action of $N$ is transitive, we have $n$ such that

$$gx=nx$$
$$n^{-1}gx=x$$
$n^{-1}g\in Stab(x)\implies g\in nStab(x)$. Since $g$ is arbitrary, we have $G=NStab(x)$.

**Corollary:** If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ with Sylow-$p$ subgroup $P$ then $G=NN_G(P)$.

**Proof:** Set $\Omega$ as all Sylow-$p$ subgroup of $N$ and notice that you can apply Frattini argument. Then the result follows.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frattini%27s_argument), Frattini's argument is a bit different: it says that if $H\unlhd G$ and $P$ is a Sylow subgroup of $H$, then $G=N_G(P)H. How does this statement imply the one in your answer?

Comment: What I wrote is more general. Yours is corallary of it. $H$ acts its sylow p groups transitivly and since $H$ is normal in $G$, $G$ also acts sylow p subgroups of $H$. By above argument, $G=HStab(P)$. But since our action is by conjugation, we have $G=HN_G(P)$. But both result is called as Frattini argument. If you wish I can write the proof of Frattini argument.

Comment: I guess it is "safer". This question arises from an exercise lesson _way before_ this argument was even mentioned, and I don't know which form was proved in class nor in which lesson, and to look for it would take decidedly too long. Could you prove your statement please?

Comment: Could you add the last comment as a bonus to the answer?

Comment: I edited the answer.